# Min height 100% sidebar - creates a gap below when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you look here, you can see that if there's a scrollbar on the right, the sidebar on the left, which is supposed to fill the whole body creates a gap at the bottom.

```
**CSS**

html, body {
    height: 100%;    
    min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
    background: black;
    width: 260px;
    float: left;
    height: auto !important;
}
.wrapper, .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;    
}

.content {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 700px;
}


footer {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: center;    
}
​

**HTML** 

<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <nav> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac ligula congue felis accumsan scelerisque sed eu risus. Nulla sed leo velit. Sed at commodo orci. Nam vitae varius risus. Vestibulum facilisis tortor aliquam orci rutrum vestibulum. Cras tincidunt pretium mauris non tristique. Vestibulum et justo tortor, at facilisis erat.</p>
                <footer>
                    <p>FOOTER</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/567/

And a screenshot of what happens

[image: Problem]
I'd like the black to continue down the page to the bottom of the content.

I've realised that the 100% height does still work, but it seems to fill the window and not keep going to fill the content.

I could use the faux columns technique but ideally I'd like to resolve this in css and I'm open to using jquery too.

Cheers

Comment: I expect it to fill the window if the content doesn't expand below the fold, and if it does, the side bar fill the whole way down to the bottom of the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ive found is using jquery

```
var contentHeight = $(".content").outerHeight();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".sidebar").css('min-height', contentHeight);
    });
```

It uses a variable to get the height of the content, and then applies this value to the sidebar as a min-height, so that if someone has a small viewport or the content is extremely long it will apply the min-height of the content.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5YHX7/578/ check this example. you need to make your sidebar fixed and float some elements to the right. hope it helps.

highlighted css changes:

```
 .sidebar {
  background: black;
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
  height: auto !important;
  position:fixed;
 }

 .content {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 700px;
 }


 footer {
  float: right;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;    
}
```

Comment: That does the job, and I have considered that, however, if a user has an incredibly small window, the menu may not fit in the view port, causing it to be cropped :(

Comment: how small? We can find a solution for everything

Comment: say 400px high, I'm currently looking into creating a solution with jquery, so get the document height and apply that to the sidebar. Not sure how possible / reliable that is though!

Comment: Think i have a potential solution : 
`var contentHeight = $(".content").height();
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".sidebar").css('min-height', contentHeight);
   });`
It takes the height of the content and applys that to the sidebar as a min-height, so if they do have an extremely small window, it will apply that value

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but my solution is a css only based solution. Instead of giving the sidebar a 100% height via js (jquery) I created an element before the sidebar with the same colour and width that is fixed:

```
sidebar:before {
    content: " ";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution for when I had a fold out menu in my navbar that couldn't be fixed because of a need to scroll (dynamic menu length)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just put margin:0; in the body and you are done.

```
html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin:0;
        }
```

full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin:0;
        }
        .wrapper
        {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        .sidebar
        {
            background: black;
            width: 260px;
            float: left;
        }
        .wrapper, .sidebar
        {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .content
        {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 15%;
            width: 700px;
        }


        footer
        {
            float: left;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <nav> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac ligula congue
                felis accumsan scelerisque sed eu risus. Nulla sed leo velit. Sed at commodo orci.
                Nam vitae varius risus. Vestibulum facilisis tortor aliquam orci rutrum vestibulum.
                Cras tincidunt pretium mauris non tristique. Vestibulum et justo tortor, at facilisis
                erat.</p>
            <footer>
                    <p>FOOTER</p>
                </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Already have 0 margin and 0 padding on it, still produces the same

Comment: yeah, it still produces the same, sorry, on my stripped down code I didn't include my reset that shows the margin: 0 etc :)